# How to trim sValue in jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

I have a jqgrid with single column search. When in the search form we enter any value with space and equal operand it does not find the value. I want to trim the value before the search is triggered.

Can some one point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you can use options analog to editrules (e.g. custom_func:validateInput).
So it should be possible for you to define your own validation function:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
       ...
        colModel:[
                    {
                        name: 'colName',
                        ...
                        searchrules:{
                              custom_func:validateInput
                        }
                        ...
                    },
       ...
    }
}


function validateInput(sSearchValue,sColName){
    var sValue = sInputValue.trim();
    ...
}
```

I did not test it, but I think it should work.
Hope it helps.